# PHP can't send mail to webmail

Tags: email, php, webmail

I have a contact form in website that if you submit it will send to webmail. 
example :

```
    $isi_pesan = $message;
    $additional_headers = "From: ".$email."" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $email";   
    $subject = 'Pesan untuk engineering.co.id';

    $to = 'info@engineering.co.id';
 // $to = 'dy_qie21@yahoo.com'; //this works

    if(mail($to, $subject, $isi_pesan, $additional_headers))
        echo '<div class="success-msg">Success !</div>';
    else
        echo '<div class="error-msg">Failed !</div>';
```

the message i got is "success !" but i got nothing in inbox webmail. PHP mail works if $to is not a webmail. so what setting i have to change to get the mail works in webmail? thanks in advance.

Comment: `mail()` function usually uses sendmail on Linux servers. Please check whether your server has mail settings [configured](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php). If not, you can use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) with any SMTP or POP3.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked in the SPAM folder?
Take a look to this PHP class

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->AddAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion, but still got no message in webmail :( how can i check if the message has been sent to spam folder?

Comment: are you using gmail or your domain email?

Comment: i set the $mail->from based on the email submitted in contact form, and $mail->AddAddress i set it to my domain email

Answer (score 3):

PHP does not itself deliver mail. It simply hands it over to a local mail delivery system. So check your outgoing mail server's logs. perhaps the email was rejected as spam. perhaps it's been delayed for greylisting, etc...

in layman's terms, PHP's mail() is the equivalent of walking down the block and dropping a letter into a mail box. Once the letter's in the box, PHP's job is done and it'll report true. Then the post office has to come pick up the letter, taking it to the sorting plant, send it onwards (airplane? truck? boat?). The post office at the destination has to accept the delivery, do more sorting, put the letter into a truck, drop it in someone's mailbox, etc...

IN the grand scheme of things, PHP's mail() function does about 0.1% of the process of delivery mail, and you've shown it succeeds. So start analyzing the other 99.9% to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: thank you for replies, i tried to figure out what happens.. how to check mail server's logs??

Answer (score 2):

If that is your exact code, then you're overwriting the first to address with the second here:

```
$to = 'info@engineering.co.id';
$to = 'dy_qie21@yahoo.com'; //this works
```

If you want to send to both, then you need to do something like:

```
$to = 'info@engineering.co.id, dy_giel21@yahoo.com';
```

Comment: I've just seen your edit to comment out the second $to assignment. In that case, you probably need to look further down the line as suggested by Marc B.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your webmail in Microsoft outlook. Now you will receive mails from contact form.
It worked for me. ;p